# Implementing search result for searching inside dictionary?

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, uisearchbar

I have a dictionary like,

```
var DataDict:[String:[String]] = [String:[String]]()

DataDict[“fruits”] = [“apple”,”orange”,”pineapple”,”grape”]
DataDict[“vehicle”] = [“car”,”cycle / scooter“,”bike”]
DataDict[“colours”] = [“black”,”white”,”yellow”,”green”,”blue”]
```

so when I search in the search bar, if the `searchText` is **fruits** then the `tableview` should display the full array of fruits, or else whatever the searchText matches to the single object inside each key of DataDict?

So how will I achieve that to display the `tableview`. I need to implement that in `searchBar` **textDidChange** delegate.

Finllay I need to the display the result as, `DataDict` object as title and It's respective `key` as Subtitle.

ex:

```
apple
fruits

pineapple
fruits
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
var DataDict:[String:[String]] = [String:[String]]()

DataDict["fruits"] = ["apple","orange","pineapple","grape"]
DataDict["vehicle"] = ["car","cycle / scooter","bike"]
DataDict["colours"] = ["black","white","yellow","green","blue"]

let filterarray = Array(DataDict.keys).filter { $0.contains("searchText")}

print("\(filterarray)")

for string in filterarray {

    print("\(DataDict[string]!)")
}
```

Now you can display the as your requirement with filterarray

Comment: hey, this seems good to me. But this only filter the keys, right?

Comment: yes for array of keys you will need to filter again and prepare the final filteredData array by combinig them as per your requirement for your tableview

Answer (score 1):

```
try below method for searchingtext. Result can be displayed to table 

func searchText(string:String) -> [String] {
        let text = string
        var DataDict:[String:[String]] = [String:[String]]()

        DataDict["fruits"] = ["apple","orange","pineapple","grape"]
        DataDict["vehicle"] = ["car","cycle / scooter","bike"]
        DataDict["colours"] = ["black","white","yellow","green","blue"]
        var searchedItems = [String]()
        for key in DataDict.keys {
            if text == key {
                if let items = DataDict[key]  {
                    searchedItems.removeAll()
                    searchedItems.append(contentsOf: items)
                }
                break;
            }
            else {
                if let items = DataDict[key]  {
                    let filterd = items.filter({ (x) -> Bool in
                        return x.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
                    })
                    if filterd.count > 0 {
                        searchedItems.append(contentsOf: filterd)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        print("SearchedItems: \(searchedItems)")
        return searchedItems
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may get array in this way also for faster response..

```
let arrTemp = Array(DataDict.keys).filter { $0.contains(searchBar.text!)}
print(DataDict[arrTemp[0]])
```

Hope it will work for you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know its kind of late , but wanted to post an improved answer with the use of flatMap and filter.

```
var DataDict:[String:[String]] = [String:[String]]()

DataDict["fruits"] = ["apple","orange","pineapple","grape"]
DataDict["vehicle"] = ["car","cycle/scooter","bike"]
DataDict["colours"] = ["black","white","yellow","green","blue"]

let searchText = "orange"

func search() {
    var resultsArray = [String]()
    if DataDict[searchText] != nil {
        resultsArray = DataDict[searchText] ?? []
    }else {
        resultsArray = DataDict.flatMap{$0.1}.filter{ $0 == searchText}
    }

    print(resultsArray)
}
```

With the use of flat map you do not need to iterate each array of string as it flattens your nested dict into one. For more info on flatMap https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/higher-order-functions-in-swift-filter-map-reduce-flatmap-1837646a63e8
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create Empty array and initialize it will first key of the **DataDict** and make it the **dataSource** of the **tableView**

then every search replace it's contents with the new one that matches the search and reload the **tableView**